# Is showing that the difference is zero a valid proof?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I want to prove that $$A(x)=B(x),\forall x$$

Is showing that for all $x$, $$A(x)-B(x)=0$$ a valid proof? Alternatively, I can use induction, but it is tedious while showing the difference is always zero is very concise.

Comment: $A(x)=B(x)$ is exactly the same thing as $A(x)-B(x)=0$.

Comment: Yes. ----------

Comment: Could you explain how you could use induction for $A(x)=B(x)$ and why it is tedious, and if it is indeed tedious, how $A(x)-B(x)=0$ would make it any easier and concise? Do you have any specific $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ in mind, and any range for $x$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are equivalent, you can both add and subtract both sides while it is still equivalent.